# How to compress a file in UNIX?

Tags: unix, compression

I want to do an ordinary "`zip`", so my `CW3` file becomes `CW3.zip`. I have tried to use some example commands found on the internet but they don't seem to work.

I have tried the following, resulting in the error below:

```
$ zip CW3
zip error: Nothing to do! (CW3.zip)
```

I also tried:

```
compress -If CW3
```

Bottomline: how do I compress a file in UNIX?

Comment: Post what you have tried and why it's failing (e.g. error messages).

Comment: Is zip package installed? zip are uncommon on *nixes as they use more often tar derivatives (i.e. tar+gz tar+bzip2 and increasingly tar+xz).

Comment: @Macej: I think it's installed correctly, "Nothing to do!" is an usual `zip` output.

Comment: Not a programming question, I suspect. A Unix command question. Wrong site.

Answer (score 7):

zip syntax is

```
zip archivefile1 file1 file2 file3
```

for compression,

```
unzip archivefile1
```

for decompression.

So in your case, for compression:

```
zip CW3.zip CW3
```

See [here](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/a/blcmdl1_zipx.htm).

Answer (score 3):

If you are flexible about the format, you can compress a file in Unix doing just that :-)

```
 compress some_file
```

downside: you need to specify every single file to compress.

You can also use `zip`, not always available on UNIX platforms, or gzip. While `compress` and `gzip` just compress a single file, `zip` is a tool that handles packaging of one or many files or directories and compression all in one go. The traditional UNIX philosophy is to have one tool for one job, making it easier for the tool's creator to make the tool excel at that one job, explaining why compress and gzip only compress, and do not package. For you as a user that means you will use use one tool for packaging, and then another to compress the package (or "archive"), if you are not using zip, but UNIX native `tar`, the tape archiver, to package first:

```
tar -c -f archive_name.tar some_file some_dir
```

will pack `some_file` and `some_dir`, recursively, in the archive `archive_name.tar`.

now compress it:

```
gzip archive_name.tar
```

will give you the compressed file `archive_name.tar.gz` (and delete the original `archive_name.tar`).

But wait, there is more: it is actually so common to compress archives, that tar can call gzip, in one command:

```
tar -c -z -f archive_name.tar.gz some_file some_dir
```

will give you `archive_name.tar.gz`, containing `some_file` and `some_dir`, packaged recursively, and compressed.

For more info:

```
man 1 tar
```

Comment: man, if you actually spend time making taste judgements about my utterings, why not fix the typos, too...

Answer (score 1):

`zip` is usually not installed by default.  It is more of an archiving tool than a single file compression tool.

Either `gzip` or `compress` should be installed.  They are files compression tools which add a `.gz` or `.Z` extension to the compressed file.  The `bzip2` program may also be installed.

`gzip` and `bzip2` are usually install with a suite of programs to `cat`, `diff`, or `grep` files.  These would be `zcat`, `zdiff`, and `zgrep` or  `bzcat`, `bzdiff`, and `bzgrep` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do

first way: zip  
           example zip cw3.zip *.sh

The above command will zip all *.sh files in  cw3.zip

second way: If you want to zip all files which are in sub directories as well 
           zip -r   
           example zip cw3.zip *.sh